# How to modify the following proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The problem is prove that for any $x$,$n$ inequality $$\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{\sin kx}{k}\right|<2\sqrt{\pi}.$$holds.I know this question has been asked, but the proof process is not what I want. The following is my thinking about this question.
Obviously, we only need to consider the case of $x\in(0,\pi)$.First,we have
$$\left|\sum\limits_{k=m}^{n}\sin kx\right|=\dfrac{|\cos(m-\frac{1}{2})x-\cos(n-\frac{1}{2})x|}{2\sin\frac{x}{2}}\leqslant\frac{1}{\sin\frac{x}{2}}.$$
Let$S_k=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}\sin kx$,andusing Abel transformation we have
$$\sum\limits_{k=m+1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\sin kx=\sum\limits_{k=m+1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)S_k+\frac{S_n}{n}-\frac{1}{m+1}S_m(\forall m\geqslant0).$$
Now,if we consider$\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{x}$, we can always find$q\in\mathbb{z}^+$to satisfy it
$$q\leqslant\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{x}<q+1.$$
So according to $|\sin kx|\leqslant|x|$we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{\sin kx}{k}\right|&\leqslant\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{q}\dfrac{\sin kx}{k}\right|+\left|\sum\limits_{k=q+1}^{n}\dfrac{\sin kx}{k}\right|\\&\leqslant\sqrt{\pi}+\frac{1}{\sin\frac{x}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{q+1}-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{q+1}-\frac{1}{n}\right)
\end{aligned}$$
Note that $\sin\dfrac{x}{2}>\dfrac{x}{\pi}$and$(q+1)x>\sqrt{\pi}$.If we can explain that
$$\frac{1}{q+1}-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{q+1}-\frac{1}{n}\leqslant\frac{1}{q+1}.$$
Then I can prove it, but I'm stuck here. Can you answer my questions?thank you.

Comment: Your last inequality is $2 / (q + 1) - 1 / n - 1 / (n + 1) \le 1 / (q + 1)$, clear fractions and work from there.

Comment: @ vonbrand but I only got $\frac{1}{q+1}-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{q+1}-\frac{1}{n}\leqslant\frac{2}{q+1}$